# CakePHP check permission by group name instead of ID

Tags: cakephp, acl

I'm using CakePHP 2.5.2 and I want to do an ACL check whether an user is allowed to use the desired aco. 
Is this possible to check this by group name instead of groupID?

```
if ($this->Acl->check(array('model' => 'Group', 'name' => $aroName), $aco))
```

When I use this, CakePHP gives me the error that it can't find the node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [API](http://api.cakephp.org/2.5/class-AclNode.html#_node), the check method accepts :

> string|array|Model $ref optional null
>
> ```
> Array with 'model' and 'foreign_key', model object, or string value
> ```

you can try to find the group object by name and then pass it to Acl->check

**Edit :**

```
    $this->loadModel('Group');
    $this->Group->recursive = -1;
    $node = $this->Group->findByName('Admin');
    CakeLog::write('debug',json_encode($this->Acl->check($node,'Users')));
```

Comment: That's what I'm showing in my example of the question. That doesn't work for me.

Comment: you are not passing a model object just an array : in AclNode.php line 130  130:         } elseif (is_object($ref) && $ref instanceof Model) {
131:             $ref = array('model' => $ref->name, 'foreign_key' => $ref->id);

Comment: Can you give me an example of how I can pass an object into it?

Comment: updated the answer, i've tried the following in beforeFilter at AppController.php it should work anywhere as long as you can load the necessary stuff (try ClassRegistry::init('Group'); if you cannot use loadModel() )